# get_children() returns ALL attachments instead only those attached to 'post_parent'

Tags: get-children

I want to pull four random images from the current post's attachments to display as "featured images". Therefor I am using the following function:

```
function fs_gallery_featured_thumbs( $post_id ) { 
    // DEBUG: validate parent post ID
    echo $post_id;
    // Query to get images for this post
    $query = array(
        'post_parent'       => $post_id,
        'post_type'         => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
        'order'             => 'RAND',
        'exclude'           => get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) );

    $images = array_rand( get_children( $query ), 4);    
    // If images exist for this page
    if ( $images ) {
        echo '<div class="featured-thumbs">';
        $i = 1;
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            $imageAttributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'gallery-thumbnail-1x1' );
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="featured-thumb-link featured-thumb-link-'.$i.'"><img src="'.$imageAttributes[0].'" alt="'.the_title_attribute(array('echo'=>0)).'" class="featured-thumb featured-thumb-'.$i++.'" width="152px" height="152px" /></a>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

The only parameter is passed from inside the loop via `the_ID()` and is in fact returning the correct parent post ID (I verified this using `echo $post_id;` inside above function.

However, for some reason, the array `images` contains four random items of ALL images that are inside the media gallery, not only the ones which are attached to the current post.

How can I really only get the images which are attached to the post? When I use the `[gallery]` shortcode in this post, the correct images are shown. All I want is four random images from that gallery.

Any ideas?

Not sure if this has anything to do with it: the posts which all the other (wrong) images were attached to, were deleted at some point. The images still linger inside the media gallery however, however the post ID of the post they are "used in" (not sure about the correct English term here, my WP is German) is different to my `post_parent`.

Thx.

Comment: Why are you debugging using `$post_id`, but calling `$post->ID` in your args array?

Comment: Sorry I realized that a minute after posting and already changed it in th eoriginal question as well as the actual code. However it doesn't make a difference. `post_parent` is still correct, but ALL images appear (well 4 of them).

Comment: For debugging purposes, what happens if you 1) pass an explicit string rather than a variable to `post_parent`? And 2) pass `0` to `post_parent`?

Comment: Thanks Chip, that did the trick. I passed `88` (which is the correct post ID) to the function and it worked; I then passed `$post->ID` rather than `the_ID()` and it also seems to work. It seems that it was only a stupid mistake. If you write an answer I will happily accept it. Cheers.

Comment: One more question: where, *exactly*, are you passing `the_ID()`? It doesn't appear in your code, that I can see.

Comment: You're right. What I do: in my template that I use to display posts within the standard loop, I make a call to above function: `fs_gallery_featured_thumbs( $post->ID )` (originally I used `the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID` which gave me trouble. I guess bescause `the_ID()` actually echoes the ID, rihgt?).

Comment: Bingo! That was the bit I needed... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hat I do: in my template that I use to display posts within the standard loop, I make a call to above function: `fs_gallery_featured_thumbs( $post->ID )` (originally I used `the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID` which gave me trouble. I guess bescause `the_ID()` actually echoes the ID, rihgt?).

Exactly. The problem isn't in your function itself, but rather in the parameter you pass to it. Because `the_ID` *echoes* rather than *returns* its value, the actual function was getting passed `NULL`, resulting in attachments for *all posts* being queried.

Solution:

- Pass `$post->ID` (in a context where `$post` is globalized)
- Pass `get_the_ID()` (inside the Loop)